# Trying to update row with 3 primary keys doesn't work

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table with 3 primary keys for a row and whenever i tried to update this row i get "Cannot insert duplicate values", but im trying to update that row using UPDATE command not INSERT ?

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.TestData
(
    OgrId int NOT NULL,
    StrId int NOT NULL,
    UserId int NOT NULL,
    ProductId int NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT PK_OgrId_StrId_UserId
        PRIMARY KEY(OgrId, StrId, UserId)
)

DECLARE @ogrId int = 99;
DECLARE @strId int = 44;
DECLARE @userId int = 1223;
DECLARE @id int = 14;

DECLARE @querySelect int = 
    (SELECT ProductId FROM dbo.TestData
        WHERE
            OgrId = @ogrId AND 
            StrId = @strId AND 
            UserId = @userId AND
            ProductId= @id);
IF @querySelect IS NULL
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO dbo.TestData(OgrId, StrId, UserId, ProductId)
        VALUES (@ogrId , @strId , @userId, @id);
    END
ELSE
    BEGIN
        UPDATE dbo.TestData
        SET ProductId= @id
        WHERE 
            OgrId = @ogrId AND 
            StrId = @strId AND 
            UserId = @userId;
    END
```

Comment: You cannot have "3 primary keys ", primary key can be only one. What you have is composed PK with 3 key fields

Comment: >>>im trying to update that row using UPDATE<<< Your code has insert command too: `INSERT INTO dbo.TestData(OgrId, StrId, UserId, ProductId) VALUES (@ogrId , @strId , @userId, @id);`

Comment: There is also if statement which selects update or insert ... And i can have 3 primary keys thats the point !

Comment: Nothing can help someone who has "3 primary keys"

Comment: I have fixed it already thanks for the replies :)

Comment: I mean, without data the logical reason is that you're triggering the insert because you have a row with matching values for the primary key, but different value for the productId.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You problem is that you are not really calling the UPDATE but the INSERT, which attempts to create a duplicate key.

This is because you are checking if a row exists for the primary key values AND the product id. When you are trying to change the same row to a different product id then your check returns false.

I have changed slightly your code, so you check for the current product id for just the primary key values, only inserting it when none is present and only updating it when it's different.

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.TestData
(
    OgrId int NOT NULL,
    StrId int NOT NULL,
    UserId int NOT NULL,
    ProductId int NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT PK_OgrId_StrId_UserId
        PRIMARY KEY(OgrId, StrId, UserId)
)

DECLARE @ogrId int = 99;
DECLARE @strId int = 44;
DECLARE @userId int = 1223;
DECLARE @id int = 14;

DECLARE @querySelect int = 
    (SELECT ProductId FROM dbo.TestData
        WHERE
            OgrId = @ogrId AND 
            StrId = @strId AND 
            UserId = @userId);

IF @querySelect IS NULL
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO dbo.TestData(OgrId, StrId, UserId, ProductId)
        VALUES (@ogrId , @strId , @userId, @id);
    END
ELSE IF @querySelect <> @id
    BEGIN
        UPDATE dbo.TestData
        SET ProductId= @id
        WHERE 
            OgrId = @ogrId AND 
            StrId = @strId AND 
            UserId = @userId;
    END
```